# Spring MVC does not detect a bean while it annotated with Component

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

A web.xml file:

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/root-context.xml, /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
```

servlet-context.xml contains:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.kb.*" />
```

spring-security.xml contais:

```
<!-- if uncoment the below line then customAuthenticationProvider is detected -->
<!--    <beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.kb.authentication.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />
 -->
    <authentication-manager erase-credentials="true">
        <authentication-provider ref="customAuthenticationProvider" />
    </authentication-manager>
```

and the main part,

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider { ...
```

The `customAuthenticationProvider` is annotated with `@Component` so why spring can not detect it? I get the error:

> Caused by:
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   bean named 'customAuthenticationProvider'

There is some error in xml configurations, what can it be?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xml configurations, then you need to add `<context:annotation-config/>` as well to your config xml **in order to spring container to locate the beans from annotations**, you can refer [here](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/4.0.4.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Configuration.html) or otherwise you need to provide the bean reference from the xml itself (by uncommenting `<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationProvider" class="com.kb.authentication.provider.CustomAuthenticationProvider" />`)

Also, along with this change, as DwB suggested, you need change `component-scan` to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.kb" />`

Comment: I aded it as you said into the servlet-context.xml. But spring-suqurity.xml still shows warning `Referenced bean 'customAuthenticationProvider' not found` and I get the same error.

Comment: You need both the things

Answer (score 1):

Short answer:
Use the correct base package name.

Longer answer:
This is not the base package name: `com.kb.*`.
This is the dream of a package name.

Instead, use the correct base package name.  For example, `com.kb`

More answer:
The `ref="customAuthenticationProvider"` attribute in the authentication-provider appears to be the problem.
Specifically, there is no bean with a reference id of `customAuthenticationProvider`.

Try using the `@Qualifier` annotation on the CustomAuthenticationProvider class.

Comment: With both base package names the error is the same.